# D3 Equipment glitch?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just crafted a pair of shoulders for my level 11 Demon Hunter, and I can't get them equipped. I click or drag them on, and I hear the *clink* sound, but it stays in my bag. It's not class specific and I meet the level requirements. I tried crafting a different pair, but the results where the same. Exiting/re-logging in does not fix it. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: if its not lag, it sounds like a glitch to me.

Comment: Wait it out, I had a similar problem with pants the other day and they fixed themselves after a while.

Comment: @yx: Yes, I think it's a glitch...I was wondering if there was a workaround, or if I'll be forever shoulder-less ^.^

Comment: Screenshot of the whole mess, maybe ?

Comment: @Nigralbus: Do you mean a screenshot of my shoulders sitting in my inventory?

Comment: Well, of the item and its statblock, as well as your character sheet if possible. Would make things clearer, I think.

Comment: I encountered something similar and in asking in game heard about others encountering the same (and googling more so). The guy I talked to in game said it seemed to work fine the next day. Others have suggested incorrect required level on tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

Some word of mouth sources I've heard (including in the comments here) say this is just a glitch and will go away after a while. So, I decided to continue leveling, and upon leveling up to level 12 , I tried the shoulders again and it worked! The pant's level requirement was level 11. I've since noticed two things: One, my Wizard could not equip some pants whose level requirement was exactly the same level as him, and that my Barb had pants on that whose level requirement was exactly her level, and they were shaded in red. I haven't played her since the last patch so...

It seems that there is a bug that cropped up last patch (1.0.4) causing some (or all) gear's level requirements to be actually one level higher than the tool-tip.